# Our edit queue is full, try again in a few minutes

Tags: feature-request, edits

I understand why this message appears, however in my case I only wanted to see the formatting of a post (so I can see how something is done).

My suggestion is to display a warning on the editing page (even if when starting editing the queue isn't full?), then only show the existing error page if the user trys to submit the edit.

Also, could the error page be formatted rather than just plain text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use "source" link through [revisions link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/93520/revisions) for that actually.

Comment: Ahh, didn't know about that. How do i work out what the link would be (for answers as well as questions)? Is there a click-able link somewhere, as without that it's pretty convoluted.

Comment: @George, as far as I know there is two browser scripts at stackapps.com, [SE Modications](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-an) and mine called "Hidden Links"

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, although i think my suggestion is still valid.